# Insert JSON data to MYSQL instantly on JSON change

Tags: php, mysql, json

i have changable JSON file `http://91.205.205.18:8000/info.xsl?mount=/128` (it includes icecast2 statistic), and i cant understand how to check if JSON data change for parsing and inserting parsed data to database instantly. Do i need use cron for some php script every 3-5 min?

P.S. Sorry for my bad english ;)

Answer (score 0):

Write a `CRON` job, that get `JSON` data from `http://91.205.205.18:8000/info.xsl?mount=/128` and then check that received data in your database if that data is already present in db discard it otherwise save it.

Comment: I was afraid of it. Are there any other thoughts on this? Or it is the only way?

Answer (score 0):

First time you may use timestamp in database with the imported json data (This time value will be provided in the json) and after that in each process time you can check only json timestamp and if there are any difference in timestamp then just insert/update else ignore it and for this insert/update process you can create a Cron job.

Comment: How i could get timestamp value (modification timestamp of my JSON??) If i doesn't have this value in my JSON? My JSON file is generating from XSLT1 by icecast2.

Answer (score 0):

You will either have to setup a cron job to check at an interval. On a project I work on we have a section of the program checking constantly (every 2 seconds) for some xml data to change on a website.  This is the only solution if one doesn't have control of the source as we do not.

If you truly need a form of push back notification and you are in control of the source data you can use a pubsubhubub server:
https://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/

I haven't setup a pubsubhubbub server but it is the best solution if you need realtime data updates being sent from one output to a remote input.